# How to validate form input on submit in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular application, I have my form validators setup, but what I want is the form validation to be done `onSubmit`. So when the user clicks submit and the form is not valid then the `ngIf` errors get shown. My code so far is:

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Request } from '../../models/request.model'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppComponent } from '../../../app.component';
import { ServicenowService } from '../../services/servicenow.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-request',
  templateUrl: './service-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-request.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceRequestComponent implements OnInit {


  public loading = false;

  private customer_id = this.appComponent.customer_id;

  serviceForm;

  u_destination_country = [
    { value: 'Choose an option' },
    { value: 'United Kingdom', },
    { value: 'United States of America', },
    { value: 'Russia', },
    { value: 'Moscow', },
    { value: 'Africa', },
  ];

  users = [
    { id: 'Select an option', },
    { id: '1', },
    { id: '2', },
    { id: '3', },
  ];

  devices = [
    { id: 'Select an option', },
    { id: '1', },
    { id: '2', },
    { id: '3', },
  ];

  constructor(private service: ServicenowService,
    private appComponent: AppComponent,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient

  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceForm = new FormGroup({
      customer_id: new FormControl(this.customer_id),
      //u_caller_id: new FormControl(this.users[0], Validators.required),
      siebel_id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      u_destination_country: new FormControl(this.u_destination_country[0], Validators.required),
      u_phone_number: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      //u_serial_number: new FormControl(this.devices[0], Validators.required),
      u_short_description: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.maxLength(80)
      ])),
      u_message_description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.http.post("/api/inc",
      this.serviceForm.value,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      }
    ).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response
      this.router.navigate(['/incident/confirmation']);
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse);//On unsuccessful response
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/10/angular-6-reactive-forms-validation-example)

Comment: Is it possible to add (some of) your html for completeness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To protect at template level, you can use

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="serviceForm.invalid">Submit</submit>
<div class="error" *ngIf="serviceForm.hasError('yourErrorName')">
 Some text
</div>
```

At component level, it goes like this

```
onSubmit() {
  if(this.serviceForm.invalid) {
    this.serviceForm.setErrors({ ...this.serviceForm.errors, 'yourErrorName': true });
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [updateOn](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateOn) property to tell Angular to run the validation function on `submit`.

Simply add the property (which can also be applied to a `formControl` or a `formArray`) :

```
this.serviceForm = new FormGroup({
     customer_id: new FormControl(this.customer_id),
         ...
}, { updateOn: 'submit' });
```

and also don't forget to protect your submit function:

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.serviceForm.valid) {
        ...
    }
}
```