# set Angular form validator behaviour for particular validator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-forms

Is there any way we can set different validation behavior for different validators?

for example,

```
{
  field1: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
  field2: ['', Validators.required],
},
```

Here, `field1` should validate the input on change, and `field2` should validate the input on submit.

Is it possible to set behaviour for individual field of a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to let a user Submit something only for it to later fail? If a form lets me submit that means my form, as far as the front end is concerned, is valid.

However, if you want something like that then for field1:

```
form.controls['field1'].valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
...do your logic here, set the form as valid or not
}
```

for field2, you will have to set the form to run validations onSubmit:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061066/how-to-validate-form-input-on-submit-in-angular-6#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20updateOn,customer_id%3A%20new%20FormControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061066/how-to-validate-form-input-on-submit-in-angular-6#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20updateOn,customer_id%3A%20new%20FormControl)

[How to user updateOn blur in FormBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423849/how-to-user-updateon-blur-in-formbuilder)

but in essence: `field2: ['', {validators: Validators.required, updateOn: 'submit'}]`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I figured out that we can pass pretty much everything required for `FormControl` in the form of array. I have added an explanatory answer for the same. Both the questions you have listed doesn't answer how to set *different* behaviours for multiple inputs. However, your code snippet for `field2` does answer my question. There's no need to listen to `field1` changes as form's default behaviour is update on change.

Answer (score 0):

`formBuilder.group` method's input `controlsConfig` has type as `any`, but as it uses FormControl constructor, we can use all the properties available in FormControl.

FormBuilder's `group`

```
group(controlsConfig: {
    [key: string]: any;
}, options?: AbstractControlOptions | {
    [key: string]: any;
} | null): FormGroup;
```

FormControl's `constructor`

```
constructor(
  formState?: any,
  validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null,
  asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null
);
```

So we can make use of all available inputs for `FormControl` including in `updateOn` for each `FormControl` as below.

```
{
  field1: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
  field2: ['', {validators: Validators.required, updateOn: 'submit'}]
},
```